# Merge two arrays and sum values where keys match

Tags: php, arrays, sum, array-merge

How do I combine these two arrays, so that the keys stay the same, but the values are arithmetically determined?

Note - the keys might not always line up in each array, per my example:

```
$Array1 = [4 => 100, 5 => 200, 6 => 100, 7 => 400];
$Array2 = [2 => 300, 5 => -100, 16 => -500];
```

Desired output:

```
$Array3 = [2 => 300, 4 => 100, 5 => 100, 6 => 100, 7 => 400, 16 => -500];
```

Comment: A simple `foreach` should work.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange For simple arrays like above, it is easy using `foreach`. Perhaps you should arrays with different number of elements to show that its not too easy.

Comment: @Hassan - how? Because the keys might not line up - so how can I make sure both arrays are combined

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) for this:

```
$Array3 = array_map(function($a,$b) {return $a+$b;},$Array1,$Array2);
```

However this will only work if you have the same keys in both arrays (which, in your example, you don't).

If this is an issue, the easiest workaround would probably be:

```
$allKeys = array_merge(array_keys($Array1),array_keys($Array2));
$Array3 = Array();
foreach($allKeys as $k) {
    $Array3[$k] = (isset($Array1[$k]) ? $Array1[$k] : 0)
                 +(isset($Array2[$k]) ? $Array2[$k] : 0);
}
```

---

**EDIT** Just realised the above code is not optimal. Rewriting:

```
$allKeys = array_unique(array_merge(array_keys($Array1),array_keys($Array2)));
// rest of code as above
```

Actually not sure if the overhead of repeated keys is more or less than the overhead of checking uniqueness...

Answer (score 4):

You can `foreach` over each array and add them to a result array.

```
//$array3 = array();

//foreach($array1 as $k=>$v){
//    $array3[$k] = $v;
//}

$array3 = $array1;

foreach($array2 as $k=>$v){
    $array3[$k] = isset($array3[$k]) ? $array3[$k]+$v : $v;
}
```

Comment: Null coalescing would be a nice, modern touch for this answer.